# Django, PostgreSQL, set_autocommit and test cases

Tags: django, postgresql

It looks like whenever I use `transaction.set_autocommit(False)` in a test case, I get the following stack trace:

```
    transaction.set_autocommit(False)
  File "/Users/btoueg/src/python/python3.3.3_django1.6.1/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 133, in set_autocommit
    return get_connection(using).set_autocommit(autocommit)
  File "/Users/btoueg/src/python/python3.3.3_django1.6.1/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 331, in set_autocommit
    self.validate_no_atomic_block()
  File "/Users/btoueg/src/python/python3.3.3_django1.6.1/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 360, in validate_no_atomic_block
    "This is forbidden when an 'atomic' block is active.")
django.db.transaction.TransactionManagementError: This is forbidden when an 'atomic' block is active.
```

Is this normal behavior ? It looks like Django’s TestCase class wraps each test in a transaction for performance reasons.

So the question is : **how do I test my code in a Django Testcase if it already uses a transaction ?**

I'm using Django 1.6 with PostgreSQL 9.2

Comment: Why do you want to turn autocommit off?

Comment: Sometimes you need to for finer grained transaction management.  When autocommit is on, it commits as soon as an insert/update/delete is done.  Turning autocommit off lets you do a batch of those, then commit all at once or rollback if there was an error.  Wrapping in atomic, as test cases do, means it doesn't commit until the end of that block but disallows manually managing commits and rollbacks.  I also fought with this today for several hours and have not come up with a solution.

Answer (score 5):

Django `TestCase` inherits from `TransactionTestCase`.

According to the doc, `TestCase` does basically the same as `TransactionTestCase`, but surrounds every test with a transaction (...). You have to use `TransactionTestCase`, if you need transaction management inside a test.

My situation is a little bit different because my test class is derived from DRF `APITestCase`. So in order to check transaction management in my test case, I did the following:

```
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase
from django.test import TestCase

class MyTestCase(APITestCase):

    def _fixture_setup(self):
        super(TestCase, self)._fixture_setup()

    def _fixture_teardown(self):
        super(TestCase, self)._fixture_teardown()

    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I came here to post exactly that about needing to use TransactionTestCase now.  In <1.5 transaction.commit_manually() worked (or appeared to work at least...) in a regular TestCase.  I'm sure using TransactionTestCase was intended all along, but the docs didn't make it clear that it was required now.